# R markdown ; DT: datatable options for columns width

Tags: r, datatables, markdown, dt

I am struggling to adjust tables in the an html document generated by a R markdown script. The columns headers are not aligned with the columns content (see image).

[image]

I am trying to set DT.options like this :

```
options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 15,
                          language = list(search = 'Filter:'),
                          dom = 'Bfrtip',
                          scrollX = TRUE,
                          buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
                          autoWidth = TRUE,
                          fillContainer=TRUE,
                          columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-left', targets = "_all"))))
```

And I declared this output type in the yaml parameters at the beginning of the script:

```
output:
    html_document:
        theme: simplex
        toc: true
        toc_float:
            collapsed: true
            smooth_scroll: true
```

In the script, tables are built from data then displayed with simples chunks like `df %>% datatable()

Can someone give me some hints of what I'm doing wrong ?

Since it's my first time working this kind of code (and it's a script I've been given, I'm not the original author), I might miss some code parts that are also important.

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a full code which produces this output ? (with a minimal dataset) That would be easier to help you.

Comment: and please try `div(style = 'width:500px;margin:auto', DTOutput("table"))`

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I just had to remove some css for tables which was interfering